# Changing service reference endpoint at runtime, sometimes the wrong endpoint is used

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF service that in turn has a service reference to some other SOAP endpoint. This endpoint has an identical copy at another address with the same metadata but different data. When a request comes in to my service, it specifies which of the two identical endpoints that I consume it wants data from. So, I have something like this:

```
 using (var client = new ServiceClient())
 {         
     client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(url);                

     //do some work, pull some data, bake some muffins

 }
```

This sometimes doesn't work when I have two requests coming in very close together with different urls. The second request ends up going out to the same endpoint as the first one. I understand that once the channel is open I can't change the endpoint, but I thought the client would only be used once and then disposed. Is there some optimization going on where the same proxy is being re-used for multiple requests? What's a good approach to problems like this?

**EDIT:** More detail:

The snippet is part of a method (let's call it foo()) that's exposed to consumers of my RESTful service. It is not static. The endpoint url is a local string that's supplied as part of the URI.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "getStuff?url={url}")]
 string foo(string url);

public string foo(string url)
{
     using (var client = new ServiceClient())
     {         
         client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(url);                

         //do some work, pull some data, bake some muffins
         return "SO rocks!";
     }
}
```

I haven't set up anything explicit for concurrency control. I understand the theory behind it but lack technical experience, so any hand-holding would be very appreciated.

**Also!** There was a semi-valid reason to change the endpoint address rather than specify it in the proxy constructor. However, for testing purposes I just tried specifying in the constructor and it appears to be working perfectly (thanks JMeter!). With a little bit of work I could restructure the real code to work that way, but I would still be very grateful for an explanation. Learning is important.

Comment: You haven't provided much details..
Is this code snippet part of a static method? How is the url field coming in and maintained within the scope? What is the InstanceContext and ConcurrencyControl setup for the service? etc.
Also, please go through this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx - link and ensure you are not relying on the c# using statement and instead manually closing/aborting the client.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question. I also went through the article, although it doesn't seem to be applicable in my case. There are no exceptions thrown and all of my code does run. I tried manual closing just for the sake of thorough testing, but it made no difference.

Comment: I tried your provided code and it ran fine for me for continuous calls. The order in which the endpt1 and endpt2 were passed to the REST service, they were rightly called without overlap.

Comment: Ok, thanks for checking. Perhaps I oversimplified and thought the problem was with how WCF works in general, but instead it's some quirky detail in my implementation. I'll start with the bare bones and try to build up to my current solution and test along the way to see where and why it breaks.

Comment: did you tried using custom ProxyBase ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at ClientBase`1 source, you'll notice that Endpoint is actually retrieved from the underlying ChannelFactory:

```
public ServiceEndpoint Endpoint
{
    get
    {
        TryDisableSharing();
        return GetChannelFactory().Endpoint;
    }
}
```

by default, CacheSetting of ClientBase`1 uses CacheSetting.Default which means it tries to cache channel factories, so it seems like sometimes you happened to modify the cached factory's endpoint from 2 different clients